# pythonですべての例外をキャッチし、詳細を表示させたい。

Tags: python

```
try:
    hoge()
except:
    fuga()
```

すべての例外をキャッチするために上のように書いたのですが、その例外の詳細を出力させるにはどうしたらよいですか？

Comment: [Pythonでtry exceptの書き方と、エラー内容の取得方法](http://symfoware.blog68.fc2.com/blog-entry-873.html) が参考になるかと思います。

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`traceback`モジュールの`print_exc()`を使えば、スタック情報も表示します。

```
def f1(a, b):
    return f2(a) + f2(b)

def f2(x):
    return 1.0 / x


try:
    f1(1.0, 0.0)
except:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
```

出力は:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Miniconda\Scripts\test_traceback.py", line 9, in <module>
    f1(1.0, 0.0)
  File "C:\Miniconda\Scripts\test_traceback.py", line 2, in f1
    return f2(a) + f2(b)
  File "C:\Miniconda\Scripts\test_traceback.py", line 5, in f2
    return 1.0 / x
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Answer (score 9):

sysモジュールの[`exc_info()`](http://docs.python.jp/3.4/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info)で現在処理中の例外を参照できます。

```
try:
    hoge()
except:
    print(sys.exc_info())
```

Answer (score 8):

`traceback`の情報じゃなくて、ただ、メッセージが知りたいなら、Exceptionの`args`が使えます（tupleが返される)：

```
def hoge():
    return 1.0/0   

try:
    hoge()
except Exception as e:
    print("例外args:", e.args)
    fuga()
```

ただし、pythonでは、詳細なExceptionを指定しないことは、勧められていないですね。

> Errors should never pass silently. エラーが起こっているのにそれがわからないなんてのは×
>
> Unless explicitly silenced. 「そのエラーは通知しなくてもいいよ」と明示的に指定されたのなら話は別だけど

http://www.lifewithpython.com/2013/01/pep-20-the-zen-of-python.html

できれば、期待している例外を指定するといいです。

上記のものの代わりに下記のものの方がいいでしょう：

```
try:
    hoge()
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print("例外args:", e.args)
    fuga()
```