# 例外を見やすく表示したい

Tags: python

python の例外出力がみにくいので
例外が起こった場所だけをピンポイントで表示できるようにしたいです

[pythonですべての例外をキャッチし、詳細を表示させたい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6972/python%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%B9%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AE%E4%BE%8B%E5%A4%96%E3%82%92%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E3%81%97-%E8%A9%B3%E7%B4%B0%E3%82%92%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84/7008)

こちらによると例外位置を表示させるには

- sys.exc_info()
- traceback.print_exc()

の２つがあるみたいで

たとえばこんな感じのサブルーチンのライブラリ内でエラーが出るコードをかいたときに

```
import sys
import json

def sub():
  return json.load('{') # わざと例外

def main():
  try:
    sub()
  except:
    # sys.exec_info をつかう場合
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    print("[%s] %s\nat file %s, line %s\n---\n" % (exc_type.__name__,
                                               exc_obj,
                                               exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename.split('/')[-1], 
                                               exc_tb.tb_lineno,
                                               ))

    # print_exec を使う場合
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()

main()
```

#### sys.exc_info()

```
[AttributeError] 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
at file test.py, line 9
```

sub の中でおこった例外も main の位置しか表示してくれません

#### traceback.print_exc()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in main
    sub()
  File "test.py", line 5, in sub
    return json.load('{')
  File "/user/local/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

ライブラリの中まで表示して見にくいですし、
ターミナル出力にはかれてしまうので文字列で取得する方法がわかりません

#### 出力したい内容

ライブラリの中は無視したユーザファイルの中の一番深い位置

```
[AttributeError] 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
  File "test.py", line 5, in sub
    return json.load('{')
```

とだけ表示できるようにファイルのプレフィックスとかでフィルタしたいです

`traceback.print_exc()`の内容を文字列で取得できれば
１行ずつ分解して /usr/local が含まれる行とそのつぎの行は削除
みたいなことができるかと思うのですが

きれいな方法はありませんか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

スタックトレースはFrameSummary毎に分かれてますので、文字列で処理しようとせずエラーから必要なスタックだけ抜き出して表示すればいいんじゃないかと思います。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
from traceback import TracebackException
from traceback import StackSummary


def sub():
    return json.load('{')  # わざと例外


def main():
    try:
        sub()
    except Exception as err:
        tb = TracebackException.from_exception(err)

        caller = None
        for stack in tb.stack:
            if not stack.filename.startswith("/usr/local"):
                caller = stack

        summary = StackSummary.from_list([caller])

        print(err)
        print(''.join(summary.format()))


main()
```

手元ではこんな感じになりました:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'read'
  File "test.py", line 8, in sub
    return json.load('{')  # わざと例外
```